# How can i select drawn rectangle and clear it in Panel?

Tags: c#

if i draw some rectangles in panel , how can i select one of them and delete it. My code here i have write it inside panel_OnClick event :

```
g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
p.Width = 2;
g.DrawRectangle(p, e.X, e.Y, 100, 60);
p.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Do you know the Size and Location of the Rectangle you want to delete?

Comment: i can draw rectangle anywhere in panel through this line :  g.DrawRectangle(p, e.X, e.Y, 100, 60);

Comment: I know that but you have to know the location of the rectangle you want to delete.

Comment: So the width and high of the rectangle are known, but the location could be anywhere in panel , can you help me in that please !

Comment: what do you mean by "delete" it?  just draw over it with another color?  you can't really "undo" because you're not saving the previous state of whatever is in the graphics before you draw on it.  if you were drawing with an XOR pen, drawing the exact same rectangle a second time would cancel it out.

Comment: i don't know the location since i can draw in any location in panel, so how can i select any drawn rectangle ?

Comment: There might be a better solution but all I can for now is Create a listbox and store the locations of the rectangle there, then the user can select the particular rectangle in the listbox and you will clear it.

Comment: what do you mean "select" it?  you'd have to store all of the previous rectangle bounds and their colors, test for matches, then remove it, then redraw everything.

Comment: i mean select drawn rectangle then click clear button to delete selected rectangle

Answer (score 0):

`Rectangle` will have a `Region`.
You will need to subscribe to one of the following: `MouseClick`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`.

```
// assuming you keep a reference of the rectangle

void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
   if(myRect.Region.IsVisible(e.Location) {
      // perform action on myRect ... 
      // have window Invalidate(myRect)
      // Refresh() the invalidated area.
   }   

}
```

This snippet assumes that no Rectangles overlap. You can also create a GraphicsPath from the points of the Rectangle and then from that path, I believe you can create a Region that enables the actual lines of the rectangle to be selected.

**Update** *per comment*

[Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I checked and I didn't see the `Region` property for `Rectangle`. So, to create the Region do the following:

```
var gPath = new GraphicsPath();
gPath.AddRectangle(rectangle);

var region = new Region(gPath);
```

Comment: what is myRect ?  i didnt create object from rectangle in my code

Comment: First comment alerts to an assumption that you are caching a reference to the rectangle. How else would you be able to know which rectangle is being selected? :)

Comment: please i want to ask what is Region ? since i have create object from rectangle to save location and size of rectangle : rectangle ob = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 100, 60);

Comment: thank u ,, please i really need another help in this : how can i open drawing file which is with .xml extension into panel, means how it can be opened in panel,here is code :      

                OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
                open.Filter = "xml file|*.XML";
                DialogResult result = open.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
                if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
                {
                    FileStream fs = (FileStream)open.OpenFile();
    
    
                    fs.Close();
    
                }

Comment: This is another question altogether.

Comment: yes its another question and need answer how can i do it please !! thank u

Comment: You have to start a new question thread for this. Sorry but questions asked within comments or *tacked* on to existing questions will not be found by others who may have the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on the panel is like drawing on a piece of paper - they are etched in and are no longer a rectangle, but a collection of pixels. Even though you could draw a rectangle over the one you want to clear using the background color, you won't be "removing the rectangle", you'll just draw a rectangle over the existing one.